# Getting daily/monthly sales for period of month/year in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen semi-similar questions but because the way my data is stored, I'm not sure exactly how to go about it.

sales table:

```
... | price | amount | weight | special | purchase_date | ...
```

- Price is a cost per 1 amount or 1 lb.
- An amount is null if an item is charged by the pound.
- Weight is null if an item is not charged by the pound.
- Special is null if there wasn't any or x/y where  for example, 2 for $3 total is stored as '2/3'. There can only be a special if the item is charged by amount. When an item has a special, it means that the item was sold at the special price. So the cost should be calculated (amount / x) * y.

I would like to get the total profit by day and by month (2 separate queries)

For now ignoring specials and for getting monthly profit, I tried:

```
select month(purchase_date) as month, sum(price * amount) as profit 
from sales 
where special is null and weight is null 
group by month(purchase_date) 

union 

select month(purchase_date) as month, sum(price * weight) as profit 
from sales 
where special is null and amount is null 
group by month(purchase_date)
```

I'm not sure if what I have is close but I am a bit confused by how group by works and so I'm not sure how to calculate the correct answer.

**EDIT:**
Added details on how special should work.

Comment: Is your specials field a VARCHAR or INT? The value of this field will be in format x/y?

Comment: It is a VARCHAR. Yes x/y is the format. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok ok. I have edited my answer. Hope it works.

Comment: Ok ok, nice, it worked. I have updated the answer as per the changes you told me. Please mark it as the answer again. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I thought it worked, but it still doesn't work for specials.

Comment: What issue are you having now?

Comment: If, for instance I add a WHERE special is not null to only get specials, it sums to 0.

Comment: Try the new edit and let me know if it works.

Comment: What I meant was the original query did not work for specials. However, I realized the mistake was on my end, it should be '(amount / x) * y)' not %. I will remark your answer as correct after that change is made. Also the SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX ... ) seems to be not needed. It can be simplified to SUBSTRING_INDEX(special, '/', 1) for the left and SUBSTRING_INDEX(special, '/', -1) for the right

Comment: Ok done. I have changed the answer to `(amount / x) * y)`

Comment: Oh, thats really nice with the `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. I will keep that in mind next time. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Here the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(specials, '/', 1), '/', -1)` function will split the data in `x/y` format into `x` and `y` seperately and then the `CONVERT()` function will convert the `VARCHAR` data type into a `DECIMAL` value for calculation.

`MONTHNAME` function will convert the month values into month names.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(purchase_date) AS Month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weight IS NULL THEN
                 CASE WHEN special IS NULL THEN price*amount
                          ELSE amount / CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(special, '/', 1), '/', -1),DECIMAL(10,2)) * CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(special, '/', 2), '/', -1),DECIMAL(10,2)) END
             WHEN amount IS NULL THEN price*weight
    END) AS Profit
FROM sales
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(purchase_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. it does't require using a union.

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(`purchase_date`) AS `month`,
    SUM(IF(`amount` IS NULL,`price` * `weight`,`price` * `amount`)) as `profit`
FROM `sales`
GROUP BY month(`purchase_date`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a single query for that. When you use aggregate function like SUM(), GROUP BY is used to get the collection of records by column you specified.

```
SELECT month(purchase_date) AS month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weight IS NULL
                THEN price * amount
                WHEN amount is null
                THEN price * weight
            END) profit
  FROM sales
 WHERE special IS NULL
   AND (amount IS NULL OR weight IS NULL)
 GROUP BY month(purchase_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` when managing 3 options. 
(the 3rd option is not clear so is have assigned it as 2/3)

```
  select 
          month(purchase_date) as month,
           sum(case when amount is null then price * weight
               when weight is null then  price * weight  
               when special is null then 2/3 
               end) as profit
  from sales 
  group by month(purchase_date)
```